# MethodInfo.Invoke returns object does not match target type

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

Ive seen other questions similar to this but i cant seem to find a solution that works for my situation.

Im trying to add a class to handle method calls and return a default
object if the method throws an exception.

Here is what ive got:

```
public class ServerConnection<T>
{

    public T2 ExecuteMethod<T2>(string methodName, T2 defaultReturnValue, params object[] p)
    {
        var result = defaultReturnValue;
        try
        {
            var baseClass = typeof(T);

            var theMethod = baseClass.GetMethod(methodName);


//next line throws error       
     result = (T2)theMethod?.Invoke(baseClass, p);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //shows Error "object does not match target type"
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `baseClass` is of type `Type`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
result = (T2)theMethod?.Invoke(baseClass, p);
```

You're trying to invoke the method on the base class' `type`.  That first argument is supposed to be the object you're invoking the method on.  That method does not exist on `Type`, it exists on the base class of `T2`!

To get this to work you first need to instantiate an instance of the target type.  **Assuming the type has a default constructor**, you can use

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(baseClass);
```

Then invoke it:

```
theMethod?.Invoke(instance, p);
```

Note that I have remove the `(T2)` cast.  You have an instance of the base class.  You can't assign an instance of the base class to a subtype.  That cast is not valid.  However, perhaps you meant to instantiate an instance of `T2` instead of the base class?  If so, just change the code above accordingly:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T2));
```

Comment: Where are getting that T2 is a subtype of T? Based on the code in the question there’s no reason to believe these two types are related in any way.

Comment: @DaveM My answer doesn't reference `T` anywhere.  Should your comment be on the question itself?

Comment: Also, it doesn’t seem likely that Activator.CreateInstance is the right thing to do here. More likely that the method needs to take an additional parameter that is the T instance to call the method on. newing up an object just to call a method and then throw away the instance is bad OOP design.

Comment: @DaveM `More likely that the method needs to take an additional parameter that is the T instance to call the method on.`  What are you talking about?

Comment: @Amy The method is a method on T

Comment: @DaveM You misunderstand, what additional parameter are you talking about?  The OP said this works.  I don't see the issue.

Comment: Doesn’t mean it does what is intended

Comment: @DaveM Or perhaps "works" means it accomplished the desired task?  Perhaps you should submit your own answer, as mine seems fine to the OP.  I don't consider any of your criticism valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working if anyone is interested.

```
public class ServerConnection
{
    public TReturn Result<TReturn, TChannel>([CanBeNull] TReturn defaultReturn, TChannel clientChannel, [CanBeNull] params object[] p)
    {
      //ignore these 3 lines if your just want the method by name
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var callerMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
        var methodName = callerMethod.Name;


        var result = defaultReturn;
        try
        {
            var channelType = typeof(TChannel);
            var theMethod = channelType.GetMethod(methodName);
            var client = (IClientChannel)clientChannel;
            result = (TReturn)theMethod?.Invoke(client, p);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("There was an error processing your request\n\nAny data received may be Inaccurate");
            //Ignored
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and here is an example of how it is used

```
        public UserDto GetUserById (Guid id)
        => Server.Result(new UserDto(), CreateChannel() ,id);
```